# Cross Entropy loss function returns 0.001 on image segmentation neural network predictions, but no prediction has sense?

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network, image-segmentation, loss-function, cross-entropy

I'm creating a neural network in pytorch that takes an 250x260 image in 3 channels as an input, and returns a pixel by pixel classification (4 classes), it returns 4 channels of 250x260 images representing each class.
This is the neural network:

```
CNN(
  (conv1): Conv2d(3, 8, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
  (norm): BatchNorm2d(8, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
  (pool): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(2, 2), stride=(2, 2), padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
  (conv2): Conv2d(8, 16, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
  (linear_1): Linear(in_features=64480, out_features=150, bias=True)
  (linear_4): Linear(in_features=150, out_features=64480, bias=True)
  (flatten): Flatten(start_dim=1, end_dim=-1)
  (t_conv1): ConvTranspose2d(16, 8, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1), output_padding=(1, 1))
  (t_conv2): ConvTranspose2d(8, 4, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(2, 2), padding=(0, 1), output_padding=(1, 1))
)
```

However, i'm using cross entropy loss function, and it always returns a loss of 0.001 or 0.000 but with predictions completely wrong, e.g:

[image: Ground Truth]

[image: Prediction]

The first image is the ground truth, there are 4 classes in total (Yellow = class 3, green = class 2, light blue = class 1, purple = class 0).
The second image is the neural network prediction in the first epoch of the NN training, i understand that the first epoch it's not that accurate, but this happens even after 50 epochs, and i truly don't understand why the Loss function returns 0.000 if the prediction it's clearly different from the ground truth.
This is the code of the training:

```
for epoch in range(50):  # loop over the dataset multiple times
    running_loss = 0.0
    for i, data in enumerate(trainloader, 0):
        # get the inputs; data is a list of [inputs, labels]
        model.train()
        inputs, labels = data
        # zero the parameter gradients
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        # forward + backward + optimize
        outputs = model(inputs)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        running_loss += loss.item()
        print(f'[{epoch + 1}, {i + 1:5d}] loss: {running_loss / 2000:.3f}')
        running_loss = 0.0
```

Do you know why loss function thinks the predictions are accurate?

Comment: Can you please show how `criterion` is defined?

Comment: criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

Comment: It looks like you are setting `running_loss = 0.0` every time through the inner loop, when it should only be reset once each epoch. Can you confirm that your code is indented correctly?

Comment: @myrtlecat is correct that your last line keeps updating `running_loss` to zero, so you get the wrong cumulative loss. However, the training should still be fine. Can you provide the code of how did you can your predictions given an input?